# Do an Event when the application is opened by a custom file? On C# .NET

Tags: events, c#-4.0

The thing is, I created a file with custom information and a unique extension, let's say (.qwas). If I modified the Registry in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT I can change its icon and choose which program will open it. What I want to do, is that when I double click it, it opens my .NET app and in the app have an event like FileOpenApp. So I can extract information from the file and do custom methods.

The kind of behavior I want to make is similar to the project files of an aplication, like the .fla of flash.

I don't know how to start with this idea, I hope anyone knows even the name of this type of procedure.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Can't you pass the name of the file as an argument to your .Net App.  Something like

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications[name of APP]\shell\open\command]
@="\"[path to app]\" \"%1\" %*"

Comment: Thanks, that would help to open the application when I double clicked the file. But I want to catch an event when that happens on the application and then extract information from the file.